# Docker over Linux but running Windows inside

Tags: docker, dockerfile, boot2docker, docker-machine

I wonder if it is possible to run Windows docker container at Linux environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is.

You can find here the list of all official Windows containers provided by Microsoft :

- https://hub.docker.com/u/microsoft/